# cxf ws-security timestamp format

Tags: java, apache, soap, wsdl, cxf

I am creating a SOAP client that interacts with WSDL at https://ws.conf.ebs.health.gov.on.ca:1440/HCVService/HCValidationService?wsdl

It's my first time implementing SOAP client and I'm using [CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/)

I'm having a trouble with the timestamp format for the request.

**Expected format** : 2014-08-05T17:46:51Z

**My format** : 2014-08-05T17:42:09.954Z

So the question is, how do I configure the timestamp so that the trailing sub-seconds are removed?

Much thanks in advance.

Relevant code :

```
    Map<String,Object> inProps= new HashMap<String,Object>();

    WSS4JInInterceptor wssIn = new WSS4JInInterceptor(inProps);
    cxfEndpoint.getInInterceptors().add(wssIn);

    Map<String,Object> outProps = new HashMap<String,Object>();

    WSS4JOutInterceptor wssOut = new WSS4JOutInterceptor(outProps);
    cxfEndpoint.getOutInterceptors().add(wssOut);

    outProps.put("action", "UsernameToken Timestamp Signature");

    outProps.put("passwordType", WSConstants.PW_TEXT);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following line of code + it should work:

outProps.put("precisionInMilliseconds", "false");

Colm.